# .Swf skips to 3rd frame

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a 6 frame .swf that is for some reason jumping to the 3rd frame upon loading.
This problem occurs in every browser except IE. I'm using AS2.
This is the actionscript for the first frame:

```
stop();

var SKUName = _root.SKUName;
var ProductImage = _root.ProductImage;
var ProductPrice = _root.ProductPrice;

var tbValue:String = String(iSize.text);

if(SKUName != undefined) {
    gotoAndPlay(6);
} else {
}
```

The 6th frame just contains a `stop();` action.

Any idea of why this is happening?

Thanks for any help.
Philip

Comment: Please format your code (indent 4 spaces or use the {} symbol).  Making your question more readable will increase your chances of getting an answer.  I did it for you this time.

Comment: Ahh, apologies. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need an preloader - Flash will start to play even before it's fully loaded and this can cause problems.

It looks like your project is AS3 so try to add something like this on your second frame (move everything else behind the second frame):

```
if (stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded < stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal) {
    this.gotoAndPlay(1); 
} else {

}
```

or this will work as well:

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, selfComplete);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I'm using AS2. Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately neither of them worked. I've noticed that everything runs fine in IE strangely, the frame just fails to stop on all other browsers I use!

Comment: for AS2 it would be: if (this.getBytesLoaded() < this.getBytesTotal()) { 
    this.gotoAndPlay(1); 
} else {

}

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the first frame problem

Comment: @user579964 - what first frame problem? Does it fix what you were asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
gotoAndStop(6);
```

if u play a frame which include stop(); twice, flash will just compile stop(); or any other script for once